# how to refine mesh in cgal in area of interest

Tags: c++, geometry, cgal

I cannot seem to understand how can I refine mesh in some part of the domain.
Namely, I can refine mesh in domain using the following function:

```
CGAL::refine_Delaunay_mesh_2(
    cdt,
    list_of_seeds.begin(),
    list_of_seeds.end(),
    Criteria(0.125,2)
);
```

How can I further refine mesh in some area of interest, for example near holes in domain, or around boundaries?
Hope my question makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain is something defined purely by constraint edges.  What you need is a sizing field that depends on an xy coordinate.  You might have a look at demo/Triangulation_2/include/CGAL/*.h